# kinectJs Rotation of two images

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, kineticjs

I have 2 images that are the upper arm and forearm. The upper arms rotates around a point and the forearm rotates round this same point.

How can i rotate the forearm when i rotate the upper arm?

if i rotate the upperarm 12 degress,then i must move the forearm to the rotation point of the upper arm and then rotate it but i cant seem to get the forearm to move back into postion after the rotation.  What am i doing wrong.

code im using for a kinectjs event;

```
//upper rotate
        upperArmImg.on('mousedown',function(evt) {  


            upperArmImg.rotateDeg(12);          

            p.x=upperArmImg.x();
            p.y=upperArmImg.y();            


            //move the formarm to center of rotation
            foreArmImg.setPosition(p);
            foreArmImg.rotateDeg(12);

            //move it back some ???                 
            foreArmImg.move(100,100);               


            stage.draw();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to joint movements is putting all arm parts in a group and then setting proper offset points.

The importance of an offset point is that they set where any arm part will rotate (==rotation point)

**Here's an outline of how to add kinetic motion to an upper and lower arm:**

- Put the upper and lower arm in a group
- Set the group, upper & lower offsets (==rotation points) to { x:0, y:armDiameter/2 }
- To rotate the upper arm, change the groups rotation
- To rotate the lower arm, change the lower arm rotation

**Group Rotation == 0 degrees, Lower rotation == 0 degrees**

[image]

**Group Rotation == 50 degrees, Lower rotation == 0 degrees**

[image]

**Group Rotation == 50 degrees, Lower rotation == 65 degrees**

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);



var lastWidth = 0;
var baseGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  x: 50,
  y: 200,
  draggable: true
});
layer.add(baseGroup);
var lastParent = baseGroup;

var appendages = [];
appendages.push({
  name: 'shoulder',
  width: 50,
  diameter: 20,
  fill: 'brown'
});
appendages.push({
  name: 'elbow',
  width: 80,
  diameter: 20,
  fill: 'peru'
});
appendages.push({
  name: 'hand',
  width: 30,
  diameter: 20,
  fill: 'tan'
});
appendages.push({
  name: 'finger',
  width: 15,
  diameter: 20,
  fill: 'wheat'
});

for (var i = 0; i < appendages.length; i++) {

  lastParent = addAppendage(i);
  appendages[i].group = lastParent;

  var appendage = appendages[i];
  var html = "Rotate " + appendage.name + ":";
  html += "<input id=" + appendage.name;
  html += " data-apindex='" + i + "'";
  html += " class='apRange' type=range min=0 max=90 value=0><br>";
  $('body').append(html);

}


$('.apRange').change(function() {
  var appendageIndex = parseInt($(this).data('apindex'));
  appendages[appendageIndex].group.rotation(-parseInt($(this).val()));
  layer.draw();
});




function addAppendage(i) {

  var appendage = appendages[i];
  var d2 = appendage.diameter / 2;

  // new group for this appendage
  var newGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: lastWidth,
    y: 0,
    rotation: 0,
    offset: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
  });
  newGroup.appendageIndex = i;
  lastParent.add(newGroup);

  // new appendage
  var a = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: appendage.width,
    height: d2 * 2,
    fill: appendage.fill,
    stroke: 'black',
    offset: {
      x: 0,
      y: d2
    },
  });
  newGroup.add(a);

  // new joint indicator
  var j = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    radius: d2 / 2,
    fill: "red",
    offset: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
  });
  newGroup.add(j);

  // display new objects
  layer.draw();

  // save width for next loop
  lastWidth = appendage.width;

  // return latest group
  return (newGroup);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
#container {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: would it be possable for you to help me with 1 more question? I followed your code and ive what i wanted to do working well but im stuck again.

if i added a "hand" to the arm how would that work. The hand would be rotating around a point in the lowerarm. i can post a jsFiddle any help would be great, thanks again.

Comment: @fuzzydunlop. Sure, glad to help.  I've changed the code in my answer to generically create as many joints as you need.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: hi mark thanks for your help, but if you could take a look at my attempt and help me fix it that would be great. ive messed up the forearm offset somehow as it doesnt rotate properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzy_dunlop/am3mq3mm/